# How to reset a radiobutton? Set back to default

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, radio-button

You know the radiobutton? You can klick on it, then you got a simple black point in the circle. Fine. How can i get this out? I would like to reset the button, this circle should be clear. Im not able to do this, i tried everyhing...

```
this->ui->radiobutton->clear
this->ui->radiobutton->reset
...
```

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: According to the Qt reference, I have around, there aren't even any methods `clear()` or `reset()` in QRadioButton. How come, you try them out? Did it even compile for you? [QRadioButton Member List](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qradiobutton-members.html)

Comment: I don't know. But my radio button has a not-so-simple, shaded, almost-3D-like, blue dot in the circle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
this->ui->radiobutton->setAutoExclusive(false);
this->ui->radiobutton->setChecked(false);
```

Comment: And don't forget to `setAutoExclusive(true)` again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for this: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop

But if you are trying to unset/clear/reset a radio button, there's a pretty good chance you are using it wrong. Radio buttons are supposed to be used as a group. And setting one of them resets all other. Maybe you should be using a check box?